# How to Recycle a Self-Hosted WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm hosting a WCF Service in an Azure Woker Role much like [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/CSAzureWCFWorkerRole-38b4e51d/sourcecode?fileId=21645&pathId=708564178).

I'd like to be able to "recycle" the WCF Service Host on a regular interval. The problem is, I assume the service is running it's own App Domain, and I have no way to poll it for any events, nor can I share any common data between the Worker Role and the WCF Service.

For reference, here's the minimum code to host:

```
public override void Run()
{
    using(var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService))
    {
        // Configure host here...

        host.Open

        while(true)
        {
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to "restart" the host somehow every 24 hours, but i'm not sure how/what to hook into to accomplish that.

Comment: can't you just host it in Windows VM and let IIS app pool recycle it?

Comment: the service is queue-fed and dynamically spun up when needed. we have other services that are iis hosted, this doesn't happen to be one of them.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm thinking about the same thing minus the Azure. I want to be able to recycle self hosted WCF services.

Comment: Kind of... We ended-up not using Azure because of legal reasons (the kind of data we're storing). We created our own worker-role hosting solution that can spin-up/spin-down *app domains* at will. We actually configure this via Sql Server. The project to host these app domains is pretty involved. One slimmer solution might be to just spin up Console apps at will.

Answer (score 5):

The WCF service is running in-proc to your worker role right (ie. everything is running in WaWorkerHost.exe)?  In that case you can either call RoleEnvironment.RequestRecycle, or just let the Run() method exit.  Either way will cause WaWorkerHost.exe to gracefully shut down, and then the Azure guest agent will automatically restart everything.

Comment: I assume so (I don't see another process spin up). This sounds exactly like what I need. Will try it out when I get back to the office Monday